# VSCode C# extension is probably misbehaving with: Type 'x' already defines a member called 'y' with the same parameter types

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

VSCode C# extension seems to be misbehaving.
I create a new interface

```
namespace MySpace;

public interface IMyInterface
{
    List<string> GetGreetings();
}
```

and I get the errors

```
The namespace 'MySpace' already contains a definition for 'IMyInterface'.

Type 'IMyInterface' already defines a member called 'GetGreetings' with the same parameter types.
```

**When I close and re-open VSCode, no more errors**. I have to repeat it again and again, whenever I create a new type.

Any Idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes i have similar, but different errors/warnings. My current workaround is `Ctrl+Shift+P`, then type (or re-use) `Developer: Reload Window`, which is faster than manually closing and opening VSCode. Not a real answer, but might speed up your workflow. If you find something, please keep us updated :)